# SSIS "Script Task" Unable to Debug (VS2008)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis

I was able to debug SSIS Script Task but then something happened to my PC that doesn't allow me to do this anymore.  I'm hoping someone on this forum can help me as I'm about ready to send it to tech support to wipe it clean.

Problem: Can no longer debug SSIS "Script Tasks"

Noticed: It appears the .Net dlls cannot be referenced within the script.  When I Edit the script for the task, click show all files, expand the the references folder... there is an exclamation point for all references.  Then when I go to the project properties for the script and select references and the path for all the references says "The system cannot find teh reference specified".  Then when I click on Reference Paths there are none set... I add the ones I need, save, close, and open back up... the reference paths are gone again.

What I have tried (in no particular order):

1) Remove then reinstall all .Net Frameworks

2) Remove then reinstall Sql Server Developer Edition

3) devenv /resetsettings

4) devenv /installvstemplates

Any other thoughts??? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a 64bit machine?  If so, the debug script component will not work unless you set the package to 32 bit

Comment: In the SSIS package project, setting "Run64BitRuntime" to "False" corrected this issue for me.